# Using Enum to represent days

Tags: c++, class, c++11, enums

I want to represent a `Weekday` (Monday to Friday) as an enum but am not sure how to represent the data in c++. I have done some reading and have my enum class:

```
enum Day{MONDAY=0, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY};
```

But I also need some sort of to_string method in order to print the days out when required.

Currently I represent a `Weekday` in its own separate class as shown below:

```
Weekday::Weekday(char day){
    switch(day){
        case 'M' :
            weekday = "Monday";
            day_value = 0;
            break;
        case 'T':
            weekday = "Tuesday";
            day_value = 1;
            break;
        case 'W':
            weekday = "Wednesday";
            day_value = 2;
            break;
        case 'R':
            weekday = "Thursday";
            day_value = 3;
            break;
        case 'F':
            weekday = "Friday";
            day_value = 4;
    }

}
```

But I got a few looks when presenting my code to others so I was wondering if this is really the best way to do it.

Someone suggested to just use a switch to compare days and avoid making a new class at all but I thought this is more organized and on the plus side if I ever need to add more functionality to a weekday its all already set up.

I do have quite a few classes already for representing time in my program as well so maybe I am going a little crazy with the classes so I suppose I just need some guidance.

Their reasons for not using classes were something about memory and efficiency so thus I have three questions:

1.) **Is a whole new class for a weekday the best way to represent this data?**

2.)**If a class of some sort is the best way what about an enum?**

3.) **Using an enum, how can I represent the enum data as a readable string I can print to an output later?**

Sorry its a lot to unpack but I can't help but wonder if my way of making a class is truly the best way if there is a best way at all.

Regardless, thanks for the help in advance!

**EDIT: the end goal here is to compare weekdays for example Monday comes before Tuesday so I assigned a value to the weekday and I would prefer not to use any imports**

Comment: The term "best" is very opinionated.  Please clarify.  Are you looking for ease of maintenance? Least amount of space? Most efficient time? Quickest to develop?  Least chance of typos?

Comment: fwiw there is [standard chrono library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) (and it's [weekday type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/weekday))

Comment: @digito_evo for the sake of simplicity I have just included what was in my header file. I would appreciate some actual answers and not you trying to look like you know more than me which you probably do. I am just learning. I am not asking how to declare and am not asking anyone to write code for me so I didn't think it was important to include my entire enum...I have a few questions as mentioned above if you'd like to take a look

Comment: @ThomasMatthews This is for a class assignment so I am simply trying to see if there are any best practices I should be following with this sort of thing. I guess least chance of typos and most readable is what I am aiming for. Memory and time is not a concern as of now the grader will just be looking to see that I have the basics down.

Comment: @appleapple unfortunately, I was told to stay away from chrono for this task.

Comment: @Linus So you should also **learn** the differences between [scoped](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/scoped-enumerations-enum-classes/) and unscoped enums too to choose the one that fits your needs better (if you are really interested in using enums).

Comment: @digito_evo  Thank you I will take a look.

Comment: use class should has nothing to do with *memory and efficiency*

Comment: @appleapple Well then I am not sure why the grader said I shouldn't use the class for this problem. He said i was over complicating it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use a table of structs:

```
struct Enum_Entry
{
    enum Weekday day;
    const char   day_name[];
    // or const char * day_name;
};
```

and then I have a conversion table:

```
Enum_Entry conversion_table[] =
{
  {MONDAY, "Monday"},
   //...
  {FRIDAY, "Friday"},
};
```

One nice thing about the above table is that the entries can be in any order.

A less maintainable method is to use an array of names:

```
static const char weekday_names[] = 
{ "Monday", /*...*/, "Friday"};
```

The conversion method:

```
std::cout << weekday_names[WEDNESDAY] << "\n";
```

Neither one is the *best* method, they each have their strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: This seems like a `std::map` with extra steps....

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can this go into a separate file? I plan on putting this in another class I have that actually has an attribute ```weekday```

Comment: `const char   day_name[];` that's ill-formed.

Comment: @mascoj as I said I need to attempt to do everything very bare bones and stay away from libraries as much as possible for the sake of the assignment. I will read up on ```std::map``` to see if this is any help regardless

Comment: @mascoj:  In the above example, the data can be stored in *constant* memory and is available directly.  When using `std::map`, the map has to be initialized as some point.  In embedded systems, the preference is not to have `std::map` because it uses dynamic memory and must be initialized; with a data struct, I can place into FPGA or ROM and not take up RAM space.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am a bit confused on how to implement this, I have my enum, struct, and conversion table but how do I declare a new Weekday instance? I have tried ```Weekday(MONDAY);``` and ```Weekday_Entry(Weekday(MONDAY), 'M');``` but both don' work